# nodejs loops and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, loops

I can not seem to grasp the arrays function in nodejs and I am having a few problems programming it to work the way I want.

What I am doing is getting json info from an api and using that for the arrays.

I would like it formatted like this

```
array = [ { Coin:{Balance: 0, Available: 0, Pending: 0, Exchange: 0} ]
```

The output from the API looks like this

```
 [ { Currency: 'BTC',
       Balance: 3.0000000000000004e-8,
       Available: 3.0000000000000004e-8,
       Pending: 0,
       CryptoAddress: '1G29t11ioGa5cmWJKLeanbNz1TA77eS1gK' },
     { Currency: 'DGB',
       Balance: 0,
       Available: 0,
       Pending: 0,
       CryptoAddress: 'DTcrZApNRDmq41bhcPcZdhhApaLQGr7nfj' }
 ] }
```

and the script that I am using to try and add them to a new array is

```js
var redis = require('redis');
client = redis.createClient()

var bittrex = require('node.bittrex.api');
bittrex.options({
  'apikey': 'KEY',
  'apisecret': 'SECRET',
  'stream': true,
  'verbose': true,
  'cleartext': true,
  'baseUrl': 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1'
});


bittrex.getbalances(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  array = [];
  for (var coin in data.result) {
    Name = data.result[coin].Currency;
    array.push(Name);

    array[Name].Balance.push(data.result[coin].Balance);

    array[Name].Available.push(data.result[coin].Available);
    array[Name].Pending.push(data.result[coin].Pending);


    client.hget("Exchange_Rates", data.result[coin].Currency, function(err, exchange) {
      array[Name].Exchange.push(exchange);
    });

  };

  console.log(array);


  for (var sell in array) {
    bittrex.sendCustomRequest('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/selllimit?apikey=KEY&market=BTC-' + sell + '&quantity=' + array[Name].Available + '&rate=' + array[Name].Exchange, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }, true);
  };


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the .map function return the format you need.

```
   return data.result.map(function (item) {
                    return {coin: {
                        balance: item.balance,
                        available: item.available,
                        pending: item.pending,
                        exchange: item.exchange,

                    }};
                });
```

Comment: ive never used the map function before so adding it in is a bit complicated. i still cant quite figure out what to do with it.  the exchange price needs to be pushed into the array. and im thinking the others should also be taken and pushed to a new array before using it.

Comment: The Map function works on an object "data". It iterates over the object and returns the new format like illustrated above. You have to be careful and use promises or callbacks. Node is an asynchronous language so operation moves on. Make sure your nesting is correct or you use something like bluebird

Comment: i'm going to end up using something different than this. because i NEED to push variables into the array after it has been built. redis is asynchronous so when using client.hget it is adding to the last variable in the array not the one it is specific to. The last post below works correctly for everything i need but the exchange rate. and i cant figure out how to push into the proper entry using client.hget

Answer (score 0):

actually you are mistake the `for(var i = 0;i<array.length;i++)` and `for(var i in array)`

if you use the first for loop , you can use like this : array[i] ... but in the second for loop , the i contain the value what you want .

```
array = [];
```

you statement the variable without the `var` , it's a bad practise , it maybe occur the unexpected error .

```
bittrex.getbalances(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  array = [];
  for (var coin in data.result) {
    Name = data.result[coin].Currency;
    array.push(Name);

    array[Name].Balance.push(data.result[coin].Balance);
```

the data is equals the object

```
[ { Currency: 'BTC',
       Balance: 3.0000000000000004e-8,
       Available: 3.0000000000000004e-8,
       Pending: 0,
       CryptoAddress: '1G29t11ioGa5cmWJKLeanbNz1TA77eS1gK'
  },
  { Currency: 'DGB',
       Balance: 0,
       Available: 0,
       Pending: 0,
       CryptoAddress: 'DTcrZApNRDmq41bhcPcZdhhApaLQGr7nfj'
  }]
```

so just iterate like this :

```
var data = [ { Currency: 'BTC',
       Balance: 3.0000000000000004e-8,
       Available: 3.0000000000000004e-8,
       Pending: 0,
       CryptoAddress: '1G29t11ioGa5cmWJKLeanbNz1TA77eS1gK' },
     { Currency: 'DGB',
       Balance: 0,
       Available: 0,
       Pending: 0,
       CryptoAddress: 'DTcrZApNRDmq41bhcPcZdhhApaLQGr7nfj' 
   }] ;

  var array = [];
  data.map(function(ele) {
     array.coin = {
        Balance : ele.Balance,
        Available : ele.Available,
        Pending : ele.Pending,
        Exchange : ele.Currency
    }
    return array;
   });

   console.log(array);
```

tips : i don't know what is the Exchange , so i use the Currency instead of it .

Answer (score 0):

seems like it was a bit easier for what i was going for than i thought. i cant seem to get the exchange prices into place though

```js
bittrex.getbalances(function(data) {
  array = [];

  for (var coin in data.result) {
    Name = data.result[coin].Currency;
    array[Name] = {
      Balance: data.result[coin].Balance,
      Available: data.result[coin].Available,
      Pending: data.result[coin].Pending,
      Exchange: []
    };


    client.hget("Exchange_Rates", data.result[coin].Currency, function(err, exchange) {
      array[Name].Exchange.push(exchange);
    });

  };

  console.log(array);

  for (var sell in array) {
    bittrex.sendCustomRequest('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/selllimit?apikey=539221df75b74af299958012e09c3912&market=BTC-' + sell + '&quantity=' + array[sell].Available + '&rate=' + array[sell].Exchange, function(data) {
      //console.log( data );
    }, true);
  };


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several misunderstandings in your code.

- `array.push(Name)` here you appending `Name` to the `var array = new Array()`. Arrays are automatically ordered and indexed by integers from 0, so your first element is now in `array[0]` not in `array[Name]` – see [`Array()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)
- `var Name = data.result[coin].Currency;` is string e.g. `'BTC'` but you set properties to it like `Name.Balance` which can be done only to JS Object e.g `var object = {}` which stores `key: value` pairs – see [`Object()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
- `array[Name].Balance.push(data.result[coin].Balance);` even if the `array[Name]` would be a Object, you set its property `Balance`and immediately push to it as if it would be an Array, which is not. The property `Balance` is not defined before, so it is `undefined` and you cannot push to `undefined`, you have to set the property first like `array[Name].Balance = []; array[Name].Balance.push(...)`. But I assume you even do not want to set the property `Balance` to Array but store the value of `data.result[coin].Balance`, so you should do `array[Name].Balance = data.result[coin].Balance`.

**TommyK** has good example how to do it right (he even use more elegant [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function designed to modifying arrays) but I'm afraid you need to learn the basics of JS first, before continue further.

Comment: well everything but the exchange rates is working now. so i just need to learn to properly push the exchange rate into the array after it has been created. and left with an entry of 0.
You are correct and i am a beginner to javascript. i do know how arrays are normally handled but i am trying to add an easier way of accessing each one of the arrays by giving them a name. what i did above got me that far.

Comment: I don't want to bore you with technical articles. I just see you miss general understandings of JS types and I'm sure you will struggle with this handicap unless you learn something about it. JS does not have *associative_array* it has only *Array* or *Object*, [TRY READ THIS ARTICLE](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them).